# Java run slowly when animatio many of images

Tags: java, animation, timer, jpanel

I want to create a animation game by java. But it runs slowly when having image in JPanel than don't have it.

public class Multi_Paint extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
JPanel pn1 = new JPanel();
JPanel pn2 = new JPanel();

static int x=100,y=100;
Timer timer;

Multi_Paint(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    pn1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    pn2.setBackground(Color.red);
    pn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));  

    add(pn1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pn2,BorderLayout.WEST);

    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setVisible(true);
    pn1.add(new DrawPanel());
    pn2.add(new DrawPanel());       

    timer = new Timer(1, this);
    timer.start();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    moveBall();
    repaint();
}

void moveBall(){
    x=x+10;
    y=y+10;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Multi_Paint();  
}
```

}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

```
DrawPanel(){
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500,500);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       

    int x= Multi_Paint.x;
    int y= Multi_Paint.y;

    //If we decline this "try" Java will run faster.
    try {               
        BufferedImage img =  ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\pict1.jpg"));   
        double scale = 0.5 ;
        double w = scale * img.getWidth(this);
        double h = scale * img.getHeight(this);

        g.drawImage(img, x, y, (int) w, (int) h, this);


    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to read the image file **EVERY SINGLE TIME** inside your `paintComponent`?

Comment: I think it adds image into JPanel ??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is right now, `ImageIO.read` internally creates an `ImageInputStream`, writes the data into a new `BufferedImage` instance and closes the stream **every single frame**, which are expensive IO operations. That's why it is running slowly.

You shouldn't have any logic in your `paintComponent` method, or else this will slow the process down. You should rather read your image file **once** in your constructor and only access it in your paint method. Since your image file doesn't change over the course of the program, this is sufficient.

Something like this should work:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage img;
    private int w;
    private int h;

    DrawPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.img = createImage("D:\\pict1.jpg");
    }

    private BufferedImage createImage(String path) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            double scale = 0.5;
            this.w = (int) (scale * img.getWidth(this));
            this.h = (int) (scale * img.getHeight(this));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not read file with path " + path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        int x= Multi_Paint.x;
        int y= Multi_Paint.y;

        // img could be null
        if(this.img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h, this);
        }

        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.